# Yarn build - Crashes error JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yarnpkg

I have a Vue application. while running `yarn build` for that application it is failing with error as " FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Apparently not crash... only restart and the error appears again

`yarn serve` doesn't show any error

I've already try using --max_old_space_size , but it doesn't work.

```
Building for production...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[15106:0x104800000]    59679 ms: Scavenge 1309.5 (1404.6) -> 1308.7 (1405.1) MB, 17.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.183, current mu = 0.186) allocation failure
[15106:0x104800000]    59705 ms: Scavenge 1320.1 (1415.6) -> 1319.2 (1416.1) MB, 11.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.183, current mu = 0.186) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x0ed65f71e681 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: lastIndexOf(this=0x0ed64fe8cd29 <Very long string[2749756]>,0x0ed684c307e9 <String[1]\: \n>,0x0ed64fe8cd29 <Very long string[2749756]>)

    1: z(aka z) [0xed64d5f89f9] [/Users/aracelicanadas/Desktop/unilever/unilever_ui/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1] [bytecode=0xed694d21061 offset=15](this=0x0ed6cad826f1 <undefined>)
    2: prepend_comments [0xed64d5f86c1] ...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x10003927a node::Abort() [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x10003944b node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x1001aca27 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001ac9c8 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x10047f740 v8::internal::Heap::UpdateSurvivalStatistics(int) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x1004813b3 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x10047ea79 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x10047d964 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x1004860bf v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
10: 0x100486108 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
11: 0x100465fef v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag, v8::internal::Map*, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
12: 0x100467dbf v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
13: 0x10054c801 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
14: 0x1005679f4 v8::internal::String::LastIndexOf(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
15: 0x10024a531 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_StringPrototypeLastIndexOf(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.10.0/bin/node]
16: 0x354b4c8dc17d
17: 0x354b4c8918b5
18: 0x354b4d494285
19: 0x354b4d43de3c
20: 0x354b4c88a5a3
⠙  Building for production...
```

Comment: What changes have you made to your code since this started happening? Have you tried updating node and your packages?

Comment: I updated node and it works!!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Updating or using a bigger heap memory size won't fix the root of the problem.

The root is that you're probably including an infinite loop dependency in your `package.json` file.

That can happen if i.e your package name is "anAwesomePackage", and inside it's package.json dependencies, you list itself as a dependency like so:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "anAwesomePackage",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "anAwesomePackage": "latest"
  }
}
```

`npm` is smart enough to figure what to do, `yarn` isn't.